# члены класса напрямую или через методы

Tags: c++, методы

Есть ли принципиальная разница как обращаться к членам класса внутри методов этого же класса: через методы или напрямую?
У меня сложилось такое мнение, что из собственных методов обращаемся напрямую по членам, а методы делаем чтобы обращаться из объектов. Смотрел следующий пример на msdn, в нем даже из собственных методов обращаются через методы. Я имею ввиду

```
Distance operator+(Distance& other)  
        {  
            return Distance(get_kilometers() + other.get_kilometers());  
        }
```

Зачем лишний раз вызывать функцию если можно обратиться к полю как есть?

```
struct Distance  
{  
private:  
    explicit Distance(long double val) : kilometers(val)  
    {}  

    friend Distance operator"" _km(long double  val);  
    friend Distance operator"" _mi(long double val);  
    long double kilometers{ 0 };  
public:  
    long double get_kilometers() { return kilometers; }  
    Distance operator+(Distance& other)  
    {  
        return Distance(get_kilometers() + other.get_kilometers());  
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю к предыдущим ораторам - `get_kilometers()` у вас в открытом интерфейсе, так что вряд ли кто-то пойдет на ее изменение (в серьезном проекте).

А вот внутреннее представление вы можете сами изменить. мало ли, станете хранить квадрат этой величины, или сделаете ее не `long double`, а чем-то иным.

Да, обращаясь внутри реализации к полю, вы ничего страшного для интерфейса не делаете. Но в случае каких-то изменений создаете лишнюю работу для себя - отслеживать и выявлять все такие обращения напрямую. Оно вам надо?

Answer (score 1):

Косвенный вызов даже из внутренних функций позволяет сделать код более надёжным, т.к. уменьшает кол-во обращений к данным напрямую. Если вдруг с данными что-то пойдёт не так, мы всегда будем знать через какую точку (функцию) мы точно должны пройти. Собственно даже несмотря на то, что можно поставить точку останова на данные в отладчике, останов на функции работает обычно существенно быстрее.

При этом косвенный вызов таких простых функций доступа вполне легко может быть встроен `inline`, что не приведёт к какому-либо оверхеду в момент выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего, для метода Set полезно проверять аргументы на валидность. Или блокировать Get в случае, если данные не были инициализированы.
Дополнительно, при дальнейшей работе вам придется вносить изменения в логику работы программы. То может пригодится тот факт, что все обращения к полю осуществляются через метод. Вы сможете быстро внести правки в логику не производя поиск всех прямых обращений к полю объекта.